# How to vertically align buttons in form-row class in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have not been able to keep a form-row set of buttons in line when associating labels with buttons. The behavior of a button assigned to a column width, such as col-3 is different than the behavior of a button assigned with an automatic width, col-auto.

The goal is to have all buttons vertically aligned with a text label above the button.  The text label should follow the button's position as the viewport size changes.  I've tried using .align-self-baseline which does not seem to have an effect.

If I add a blank label above the button with an autosized column it places the text to the left of the button instead of above it.  The labels need to appear above the buttons as the target application is displaying on a mobile device with limited display port width.  Here are snippets of both:

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  <div class="container">
    <form action="#">
    
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-4 text-center">
          <label>Desired</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block active" aria-pressed="true">Button Name</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto text-center">
          <label>undesired</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary active" aria-pressed="true">Button 2</button>
        </div>        
      </div>  <!-- row -->
 
      <div class="form-row mt-4">
        <div class="col-4 text-center">
          <label>Desired</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block active" aria-pressed="true">Row 2 Button</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-auto text-center">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary align-self-baseline active" aria-pressed="true">Not aligned with Row 2 Button</button>
        </div>        
      </div>  <!-- row -->
 
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is in the `btn-block` class - it gives `display:block` property to the buttons inside the div with `col-4` class - if you remove it, the alignment will be similar

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
  <div class="container">
<form action="#">

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <label>Desired</label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block active" aria-pressed="true">Button Name</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto text-center">
      <label>undesired</label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-outline-primary active" aria-pressed="true">Button 2</button>
    </div>        
  </div>  <!-- row -->
 
  <div class="form-row mt-4">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <label>Desired</label>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn-block active btn-block" aria-pressed="true">Row 2 Button</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto text-center d-flex">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary align-self-end active" aria-pressed="true">Not aligned with Row 2 Button</button>
    </div>        
  </div>  <!-- row -->
 
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps I was not being sufficiently clear, I need to have the label appear above the button.  There is insufficient space in the viewport to support the label being beside the button.  For the sake of clarity, the label "undesired" needs to appear above Button 2 or the two buttons (one with a label and one without need to be vertically aligned in the 2nd row.

Comment: If you want to have the "undesired" label be above the Button 2 you need to add the class "btn-block" to it (it will display the button as a "block" element). If you want to have buttons from the second row aligned to the bottom you can add a class "align-self-end" to the button  "Not aligned with Row 2 Button" Here is more info about elements` alignment with bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Comment: In your answer you suggested removing the "btn-block" class and then in your comment you suggested adding it back; however, adding back leaves me with the original problem - when used with a col-auto class the label is in fact not placed above the button.

Your second suggestion of using align-self-end does not work.  I've edited your answer to include the change and there is no change in the alignment of the blocks.

Comment: I updated the code, please take a look. I hope this is what you wanted to achieve, if not - it'd be easier to give some image explanation of the layout that you want to have

Comment: Understood.  Just the same I thought my explanation was clear.  For other users please note, while the code above behaves as desired, when align-self-end is applied as shown and displayed on an iPhone (same result for Chrome and Safari) the buttons are not aligned.  When align-self-end is applied to a custom-select object in the same manner it responds very poorly.